# Get a list of values from lists in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a dictionary in the following format with keys and a list of attributes associated with each key:

```
inputDatasets = {
    "data1": ["Path to data 1", "Attribute1", "Attribute2", "Attribute3"],
    "data2": ["Path to data 2", "Attribute1", "Attribute2", "Attribute3"],
}
```

I would like to get a list of all the "Attribute2" contained in the dictionary. For now I use:

```
attr2 = []
for a, b in inputDatasets.items():
    attr2.append(b[2])
```

But is there a more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension, looping only through the values instead of key-value pairs:

```
attr2 = [b[2] for b in inputDatasets.values()]
```

Alternatively, but not as elegantly, a `map` with a `lambda` could be useful:

```
attr2 = list(map(lambda b:b[2], inputDatasets.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as follows

```
attr2 = [v[2] for v in inputDatasets.values()]
```